# Understanding Z3's low performance on a quantified LIA formula

Tags: z3, smt

I have come across the following formula that takes Z3 several minutes to solve:

```
(set-logic LIA)
(assert
    (forall ((f Int))
        (exists ((a Int) (b Int))
            (= (+ (* 17 a) (* 19 b)) f)
        )
    )
)

(check-sat)
(exit)
```

I have read the [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14203-1_27) documenting the approach Z3 uses to decide LIA, however, I fail to see why does Z3 struggles with the given formula. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Quantifiers are hard, nested quantifiers are harder. It's really hard to guess what's going on internally in any given SMT-solver; unfortunately. They are more-or-less black-boxes, unless you invest in studying their internals. A good book on the techniques used is Kroening and Strichman's [Decision Procedures](http://www.decision-procedures.org), which has an entire chapter on linear arithmetic. You might want to read through that book, which also contains further references.

Note that SMT solvers do better when they "try to find a model" instead of trying to prove things, so one usually asks the negation of a theorem to be satisfied instead. An unsat result then indicates theoremhood. Doing this translation to your problem, one gets:

```
(set-logic LIA)
(declare-fun f () Int)
(assert
  (forall ((a Int) (b Int))
      (distinct (+ (* 17 a) (* 19 b)) f)
  )
)

(check-sat)
(exit)
```

Unfortunately, z3 takes even longer on this form; which surprised me. (I'd have expected at least the same performance.) But [yices](https://yices.csl.sri.com) solves it instantly! (For comparison, CVC5 seems to run forever on it as well, who knows why.) So, you might want to try yices instead if you have problems of this sort.

The fact that yices does well on this while z3 doesn't suggests perhaps z3 is missing some heuristic, or a rewrite that yices has. You might want to report this discrepancy at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues. Not as a bug, but rather as a curiosity why yices performs much better. I'm sure the developers would appreciate hearing about it, even if they choose not to do anything to make z3 go faster on this problem.

Comment: According to a [paper](https://yices.csl.sri.com/papers/smt2015.pdf) linked on yices website the solver contains a heuristics aimed directly at problems with an "exists-forall" structure, giving some explanation on why yices is able to solve the given formula. I have also read the [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14203-1_27) describing how z3 is approaching linear arithmetics, however I am failing to see which part of z3's approach is problematic given the problematic formula, therefore, I have tried asking on SO.